# Can't install PHP 7.3 on macOS Catalina due to weird version error

Tags: php, macos

I'd like to upgrade my PHP version on macOS Catalina from 7.2.9 to 7.3.

When I run:

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

I get:

```
Your version of OS X (10.15) is not supported, you need at least 10.6
Stopping installation...
If you think that's wrong, try
****
curl -o install.sh -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash install.sh force
```

and if then try that last line I get:

```
bash: install.sh: No such file or directory
```

This is weird to me as macOS (OS X back then actually) [10.6 is Snow Leopard (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_version_history#Version_10.6:_%22Snow_Leopard%22) and I'm on the latest version macOS Catalina 10.15.1.

It seems like the only thing I can find on this is [here on Github](https://github.com/liip/php-osx/issues/237), but I'm not sure what to do. The solution seems to be 'download the script and then change this' but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please try and comment out the lines of `install.sh` I've referenced and re-run it. Let me know if this works and consider marking the answer if it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code here:

https://github.com/liip/php-osx/blob/master/install.sh#L68

It contains a statement which is producing that error message.

The problem is that the code only checks for macOS  versions between 10.6 and 10.13 (see https://github.com/liip/php-osx/blob/master/install.sh#L50). So anything higher than 10.13 - or lower than 10.6 for that matter - will result in you seeing that error.

You could comment-out the code block I've linked, and re-run `install.sh` as that would trick the script into not bothering with this check. Please note that this will only disable the check from occuring, so it's not a great idea to rely on doing this, but it might be enough to get the install  to complete.

I can't help further, but that's the reason why you're seeing that. Maybe drop a message to the maintainer through GitHub.